# Debugging why an element appears on page load briefly when opacity is set to 0

Tags: jquery, css

I'm sorry in advance if this question isn't deemed acceptable by the moderators.

I'm just not sure how to debug this issue because there is about 1 or 2 seconds to catch the problem occurring.

Please view [this website](http://www.clubnetsem.com/).

The opening message with the coloured blocks are set to opacity 0 and then with jQuery, after a delay, we set the opacity to 1 and use CSS transitions to create the effects.

As far as I can make out, all three blocks are built the same way yet for some reason the green block is displaying briefly on page load before the opacity=0 kicks in.

Can anyone spot why this is happening or advise on how I can get to the bottom of this, everything looks the same across all three blocks in Chrome's dev tools.

I'd appreciate any advice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should try to recreate your issue in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net); this way when your problem has resolved itself this question will still be of use to future visitors.

Comment: @James Donnelly - I was thinking of that actually. I will do that right now. Thanks.

Comment: My guess is that the element is not being hidden quick enough, so you see the initial animation. In CSS set the element to `display: none` and then use `show()` to display the element

Comment: If you want to debug, you can set a breakpoint in your JS in Chrome = F12, Sources pane;, select your JS file, put in a breakpoint by clicking in the left grey bar. You can then see what if happening to your HTML/CSS etc at that moment in time

Comment: Thanks @jammykam - working on this now.

Comment: Tried your suggestion @jammykam and the green block was still being briefly loaded before everything else. Will try adding a breakpoint. Thanks.

Comment: I got nowhere with the breakpoint because the problem is apparent before the jQuery is loaded. :(

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the issue, wasn't anything to do with the loading of jQuery.

A CSS declaration of `display: block` for a particular media query and up was overriding the base default of `display: none` for a split second before the jQuery was setting the opacity to 0.

Comment: Good old CSS overrides! Kinda difficult to track down with the JS firing off. If you suspect it is a JS issue, then either breakpoint and inspect the inheritance, or turn JS off (assume you don't AJAX load the content)

Comment: Yeah, in the end I actually purposely stopped the JS firing to see what was happening before. I don't know why I didn't think of it before. Thanks for your help.